# How to "print to PDF" multiple books using Calibre?

Tags: pdf, automation, conversion, print-to-pdf, calibre

When using Calibre's E-book Viewer, there is a button to "print to PDF":

[image]

Clicking it shows some options for "print to PDF":

[image]

I can successfully convert various ebook files to PDF this way. However this conversion process only converts files one at a time.

How can I mass "print to PDF" multiple files?

---

<sup>• Using Calibre Library, I can mass convert multiple books to PDF by selecting the books and clicking the "Convert books" button:


  [image]


  Clicking on the button opens a window that shows many options:


  [image]


  No matter how I experiment with these settings though, there simply is no way for Calibre Library to achieve the output that looks like the one we get from Calibre E-book Viewer's "print to PDF" function. As such, I don't think it's possible to do it using the converter in the Calibre Library.</sup>

Comment: Looks like you're using Windows, but you confirm your OS (&version) and what version of Calibre you are using?  I'm on Ubuntu 15.10, and it is version 2.33 from the Linux repositories; it is up to version 2.47 direct from the website.  I do not have a print to PDF button, or even the side toolbar on my version at all, so I am thinking that they have merged the Print to PDF functionality into export functions.  The export functions look to be very robust, however.

Comment: @David, Yes I'm on Windows 8.1 with latest version of Calibre too. Export seems like a completely different thing from Print-to-PDF because it looks like only a one-step conversion. There's no option to produce the same result as print-to-PDF which seems like a two-step conversion (rendering first using the Viewer, then converting the rendered output into PDF).